# wget-like display in bash script

Tags: bash

I just want to know how I can write a **bash script** that display text that updates itself : for example when using wget the percentage of downloaded files is being update **without having to write a new line**.

Comment: *cough* `tput cup` *cough*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `echo -ne` and `\r` to start writing at the beginning of the line without a newline character.  For example run this to demonstrate:

```
for i in {0..100..5}; do
    echo -ne "$i% complete\r"
    sleep 0.2
done
```